# Using Multer for uploading files in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am able to upload images using below in node JS.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var done = false;

router.get( '/upload', function(req , res) {
res.render('upload');
});


router.post( '/upload' , multer({ dest:   './uploadImages/'}).single('idUpload') ,  function(req , res) {

//-- logic for uploading file comes here
res.send('done');

});

module.exports = router;
```

As per my understanding a middleware can have 2 parameters , first the path('/upload') 
and the second call back(function(req , res).

But in the above code middleware has three paramters , second one being "multer({ dest: './uploadImages/'}).single('idUpload')"

I would like to know how many paramters are allowed for a middleware function
in node/express JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A middleware is of the form

```
var first = function(req, res, next){
      req.count = 1; //do something in this case attach count item to req object
      next(); // call next middleware 
     } 

var second = function(req, res, next){
      req.count += 1;
      next(); 
     }
```

if we want to use above two middlewares in post route you can use them as

```
router.post('/mypath', first, second, function(req, res){
  res.send(req.count) // will show 2 on response
 }
```

as in above case we could have used more middlewares.
now comming to `router.post()` it accepts path as first argument as path and any number of middlewares.
As for the upload problem make sure you have `uploadImages` directory and its path is correct and request header has Content-Type: 'multipat/form-data' with file field name being `idUpload`